# ag grid fast horizontal scrolling results in some columns not showing

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

We have an angular ag-grid table implementation on our site with a default of 8 columns pinned to the left. The problem is when we scroll fast using the horizontal scroll on the non pinned columns, sometimes the last column is not showing properly or not showing at all or sometimes more columns is not showing.

[image: Table Initial Loading]

[image: Table On Scroll]

As you can see in the first picture, that is the initial loading, on the second picture, that is the time that I scroll fast horizontally. As you can see from the scroll bar, it already reach its end but there are still 3 columns that is not showing.

Comment: This has already been fixed. The problem caused by our old css override on horizontal scroll of ag-grid.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is overwrite the translateX value produced by ag-grid

Answer (score 0):

This has already been fixed. The problem caused by our old css override on horizontal scroll of ag-grid.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
using ag-grid version 22.1.1 and perfect scrollbar version 1.4.0.

hiding the right corner element fixed the issue.

```
.ag-horizontal-right-spacer.ag-scroller-corner {
  display: none;
}
```